# Why does this code ignore the await and proceed anyway?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
public Index () {
    InitializeIndexAsync();
}

async Task InitializeIndexAsync () {
    State = IndexState.Initializing;
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
        // Initialize other things.

        await IndexAsync();
    });

    State = IndexState.Ready;
}
```

I would expect that "State = IndexState.Ready" would not be hit until the asynchronous lambda completes, but debugging shows that line is hit long before the thread started above it completes. Why is this?

Comment: What happens when you replace `await IndexAsync();` with `IndexAsync().Wait();`

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm not using ASP.NET.

Comment: @L.B Adding .Wait() halts all execution at that point, which negates the benefits of asynchronous initialization.

Comment: @Josh it is already in a task.

Comment: @L.B My mistake, I see what you were saying. The problem wasn't with the IndexAsync line, though. That was awaiting perfectly. As pointed out by Stephen and the other person who answered, my mistake was not using .Unwrap() to get at the inner task or simply using Task.Run() instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`StartNew` does not understand `async` lambdas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx), so when you pass it an `async` lambda, it will return a `Task<Task>`. Conceptually, the "outer" task only represents the *start* of the `async` lambda; the "inner" task represents the *completion* of the `async` lambda.

This is one of the [reasons that `StartNew` is the wrong choice for `async` code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), as I explain on my blog. A better solution is to use `Task.Run`, which was designed with `async` in mind:

```
async Task InitializeIndexAsync () {
  State = IndexState.Initializing;
  await Task.Run(async () => {
    // Initialize other things.

    await IndexAsync();
  });

  State = IndexState.Ready;
}
```

Comment: Task.Run is simply a shorthand method for StartNew with some specified defaults.

Comment: @Shoe: The correct options are easy to get wrong with `StartNew`, and with `async` code there's no need to use any *other* options. See my blog post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve by all these awaits...
I would try to keep it simple by having a synchronously method which initializes things, and then another MethodAsync which returns a Task and I can await on that task:

```
    public async void Index()
    {
        await InitializeIndexAsync();
    }

    private Task InitializeIndexAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => InitializeIndex());
    }

    private void InitializeIndex()
    {
        State = IndexState.Initializing;
        // Initialize other things synchronously.
        IndexAsync().Wait();

        State = IndexState.Ready;
    }
```

I hope this is what you meant.